# Python: Escape Sequence And Processing

Tags: python, performance, memory, time

I was experimenting with the escape sequence in python while I came across this scenario which I am unable to find the answer to.

I have taken a printing array containing a list of characters. These characters also include escape sequences 'b-backspace' "\b". The idea was to mimic a human hand typed typo and correction made to the type. So it would first print
"This isa_"               - Typo
"This is_"                -correction
"This is a test"          -continue with rest of the sentence

To view this in human like speed, I have imported the time package and used it's sleep method.

However, I am getting correct results if I get things faster but at slower speeds the result is
not as I had expected.

fast final output: "This is a test"
slow final output: "This isa a test"

I am using Spyder 5.1.5 with c python compiler  Python 3.9.7 (64-bit Windows)
Here is the code.

```
import time

printing_array = ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', 'a', '\b', ' ','a', ' ',  't', 'e', 's', 't','.']
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '');
    time.sleep(0.055)
print('\n')
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '');
    time.sleep(0.09)
print('\n')
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '');
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Can someone please help me with the reason why python is behaving in this way? What does speed has to do with the final output at the hardware level? Or is time module killing some memory operation that is not known to me. Hence please help me understand this interesting behaviour.

Comment: I am getting the expected output in all the cases.

Comment: It seems it's a problem specific to Spyder's console: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/195

Comment: try that in Pycharm, should be fine

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, use the `flush=True` parameter with the `print()` function. This will force the Python interpreter to flush the output buffer before the sleep function executes. This will ensure that the `\b` escape sequence is able to remove the `a` character from the console before the next character is printed.

Here is the code with the `flush=True` parameter:

```
import time

printing_array = ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', 'a', '\b', ' ','a', ' ',  't', 'e', 's', 't','.']
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.055)
print('\n')
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.09)
print('\n')
for i in printing_array:
    print(i, end = '', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I tested that in Spyder 5.4.3, and now ALL cases fail! It seems this problem was not properly fixed.

Comment: then I think the error was in Spyder IDE NOT MY CODE, I tested it in CMD, PowerShell, Cmder, and VScode and it work in all of them.

Comment: Also works fine in jupyter notebook, tbh it works even without `flush=True`

Comment: so, the problem in the Spyder IDE.
you can submit the bug here:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/submit-a-report.html#:~:text=Describe%20the%20issue%20you're,our%20issues%20page%20on%20Github.

Comment: flush = True is actually making this happen even at the slower speed. I guess this is something specific to Spyder. The same works fine with notebook and shell.